# C++ program that uses a 2 dimensional array that asks a user for two inputs twice. It needs to display those inputs as outputs

Tags: c++

I need the program to take the two inputs that are asked twice and display them twice. If the user enters the name Ben, then bday 11111995, and then the user enters Daisy, bday 11111994, it needs to display those as User #1 name: Ben, User #1 bday: 11111995, then User #2 name: Daisy, User #2 bday: 11111994. It would help if the user could enter their birthdays as 11/11/1994 and display it that way, too. I'll check back in a bit.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int personname = 2;
    const int personbday = 2;
    double    storagelabel[personname][personbday];
    int       name;
    int       bday;
    string    namelabel;
    double    bdaylabel;
    int       nameloop;
    int       loopint;

    cout << "Enter the info asked of you. \n";
    for (name = 0; name < personname; name++)
    {
        cout << "Name #" << (name + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> namelabel;
        for (bday = 1; bday < personbday; bday++)
        {
            cout << "Bday #" << (name + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> bdaylabel;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int nameloop = 0; nameloop < personname; nameloop++)
    {
        for (int loopint = 0; loopint < personbday; loopint++)
        {
            cout << personname << personbday << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make the slightest sense, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this problem up. First - write a function to ask the user for info. Then write a function to display the info. By breaking things up, they'll be cleaner and easier to understand.

#### Asking the user for info:

Since we need a name and a birthday, we can return it as a `std::pair`.

```
#include <tuple> // This is where std::pair is
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::pair<std::string, int> getUserInfo() {
    std::pair<std::string, int> info;
    std::cout << "Enter name: "; 
    std::cin >> info.first; // Read in the name

    std::cout << "Enter birthday as a number: ";
    int month, day, year;
    char separator;
    // Reads it as MM/DD/YYYY
    std::cin >> month >> separator >> day >> separator >> year;
    info.second = year * 10000 + month * 100 + day; 
    return info;
}
```

#### Printing the info:

We just take the pair as input, and print it:

```
void printInfo(std::pair<std::string, int> info) {
    auto name = info.first;
    auto birthday = info.second;
    std::cout << "Name: " << name << "\n";
    // Prints it all as YYYYMMDD
    std::cout << "Birthday: << birthday << "\n";
}
```

#### Using the functions

Now, we can ask for two users, and print them:

```
int main() {
    auto user1 = getUserInfo(); 
    auto user2 = getUserInfo();

    std::cout << "User 1:\n";
    printInfo(user1);
    std::cout << "User 2:\n";
    printInfo(user2); 
}
```

#### Improving the code with a Birthday class

Now that we've done that part, we can improve the code by making a class to store the birthday. That'll make it easier to allow the user to enter the birthday in the format they want.

```
class Birthday {
    int bday;
   public:
    // Uses the first two digits of bday
    int getDay() {
        return bday % 100;
    }
    // Uses the next two digits of bday
    int getMonth() {
        return (bday / 100) % 100;
    }
    // Uses the remaining digits of bday
    int getYear() {
        return bday / 10000; 
    }
    void setBday(int year, int month, int day) {
        bday = year * 10000 + month * 100 + day;
    }
};
```

Now, we can write functions to print a birthday:

```
// Prints it as MM-DD-YYYY
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Birthday b) {
    stream << b.getMonth() << '/' << b.getDay() << '/' << b.getYear();
    return stream;
}
```

And to read it in:

```
// Reads it as MM-DD-YYYY
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Birthday& b) {
    char separator;
    int year, month, day;
    stream >> month >> separator >> day >> separator >> year;
    b.setBday(year, month, day);
    return stream;
}
```

Because we added those functions, all we have to do is modify `getUserInfo()` and `printInfo()` to use `Birthday` instead of `int`:

```
std::pair<std::string, Birthday> getUserInfo() {
    std::pair<std::string, Birthday> info;
    std::cout << "Enter name: "; 
    std::cin >> info.first; // Read in the name

    std::cout << "Enter birthday as a number: ";
    std::cin >> info.second; // Read in the birthday
    return info;
}
void printInfo(std::pair<std::string, Birthday> info) {
    auto name = info.first;
    auto birthday = info.second;
    std::cout << "Name: " << name << "\n";
    std::cout << "Birthday: << birthday << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a structure to contain your data:

```
struct Person
{
  std::string name;
  std::string birthdate;
};
```

You could add a method that prompts the User for the data:

```
struct Person
{
  //...
  void ask_user_for_input();
};
void Person::ask_user_for_input()
{
  std::cout << "Enter name: ";
  std::getline(cin, name);
  std::cout << "Enter birthdate: ";
  std::getline(cin, birthdate);
}
```

You could also add a method for printing:

```
struct Person
{
  //...
  void print(int user_id) const;
};
void Person::print(int user_id) const
{
  std::cout << "User #" << user_id << " name: " << name;
  std::cout << ", User #" << user_id << " birthdate: " << birthdate;
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

I suggest creating a database:

```
std::vector<Person> database;
```

To print the database:

```
const unsigned int quantity(database.size());
for (unsigned int index = 0; index < quantity; ++index)
{
  database[i].print(index + 1);
}
```